# What linux user does eclipse run Linux commands as?

Tags: linux, java, user, runtime

Linux running as user x executes Linux commands using runtime.exec. What user does the command run as and how can one tell?

Yes. Eclipse running as root won't execute sudo -n commands passed into java as string, but shell as non-root will. Then if I put the commands in a .sh script, and add the non-root to sudoers and enable the user to sudo the script, the command runs but only if wrapped in the script. Also I have the command added to list of allowed commands the user is allowed to sudo. They will work in the shell, but not the direct command in java run exec, but in java run exec they run only if wrapped in a script as explained

Example: "sudo -n iptables -L -v -n" when passed into the java run exec code as String= "sudo -n iptables -L -v -n" won't run but as String= "/bar/script.sh" where the script has  "sudo -n iptables -L -v -n" inside, it runs Ok.

Comment: Do you have reasons to think it's not the same user that Eclipse is running under?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse running as root won't execute sudo -n commands passed into java as string, but shell as non-root will. Then if I put the commands in a .sh script, and add the non-root to sudoers and enable the user to sudo the script, the command runs but only if wrapped in the script. Also I have the command added to list of allowed commands the user is allowed to sudo. They will work in the shell, but not the direct command in java run exec, but in java run exec they run only if wrapped in a script as explained.

Comment: You should really add this to the question (use the [Edit] button). Without this context it sounds like a very basic question

Comment: Yeah. If you think of it, it's really quite basic, if one is able to tell which user eclipse will execute Linux shell commands as from java code.